# Installing package as editable with multiple packages with same top-level module breaks import

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-import

I have the following directory structure:

```
.
├── client
│   └── main.py
├── lib1
│   ├── setup.py
│   └── top
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── lib1
│           └── __init__.py
└── lib2
    ├── setup.py
    └── top
        ├── __init__.py
        └── lib2
            └── __init__.py
```

`lib1` and `lib2` are two different packages which both provides submodules inside the `top` module.

The `client` directory contains a python project using both `lib1` and `lib2`.
The contents of `main.py` is:

```py
import top.lib1
import top.lib2
```

When installing the two libraries by path inside a virtual environment everything works:

```
$ python -mvenv /tmp/venv1
$ source /tmp/venv1/bin/activate
$ pip install ./lib1 ./lib2
$ python client/main.py
```

However if I install one of the libraries as editable, one of the imports stops working:

```
$ python -mvenv /tmp/venv2
$ source /tmp/venv2/bin/activate
$ pip install ./lib1 -e ./lib2
$ python client/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../client/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import top.lib1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'top.lib1'
```

Is there a fix for this?

---

I'm using Python 3.9.6 and the contents of `setup.py` for `lib1` is (it is similar for `lib2`):

```py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="lib1",
    author="example",
    author_email="example@example.com",
    packages=[
        "top.lib1",
    ],
    version="0.0.1",
)
```

Comment: I think you're looking for [namespace packages](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+namespace+packages)

Comment: @phd Could you modify my example and get it to work? I can't.

Comment: Sorry, no. I have enough work at the job already. You can see my code at  [m_lib](https://pypi.org/project/m-lib/) / [m_lib.defenc](https://pypi.org/project/m-lib.defenc/) / [m_lib.full](https://pypi.org/project/m-lib.full/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I delete the two `top/__init__.py` files, then it works for me.

```
$ rm */top/__init__.py
$ cat > client/main.py <<EOF
import top.lib1
import top.lib2
print(top)
print(top.lib1)
print(top.lib2)
EOF
$ repro2/venv2/bin/python client/main.py 
<module 'top' (namespace)>
<module 'top.lib1' from '.../so68922155/repro2/venv2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/top/lib1/__init__.py'>
<module 'top.lib2' from '.../so68922155/lib2/top/lib2/__init__.py'>
```

I put the code from your question into a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Mortal/so68922155).